# 3d print toolbox

Tags: 3d-printing

something strange has happened to the 3D print toolbox tool in ONE of my models. the addon is installed and activated, the tab shows on the side toolbar, but the tool will not slide open. it was working but I must have hit a key stroke that stops the tool from sliding out. the other addons on the menu work, item, edit, view, etc. but the toolbox does not open.
If I export the file to .fbx then import it to a new blender window, the tool works fine.
I am not sure what I did but would like to continue using the same model without exporting and importing. and for future reference. any help very appreciated.

Comment: Hi. I don't know why this should do anything, but maybe try deactivating the addon, close Blender, reopen Blender, reactivate the addon?

Comment: tks for the reply, already tried that. there is something I did in the model that is causing this. If I close it and open another file it works fine. close that and open the original file and it doesnt work.